# Better way to append children in randomized order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using a trivia API to generate random trivia questions. This API has an example response like this

```
{
correct_answer = 'Angular',
incorrect_answer = ['Bad','Coco','He']
}
```

In order to make the card answers randomized, I currently opted into doing something like this

```
var mArray = [];
mArray.push(correct_answer);
incorrect_answer.forEach(function(ans){
    mArray.push(ans);
});
mArray.shuffle()
mArray.forEach(function(ans){
    $container.append('<span>'+ans+'</span>')
})
```

However, I felt like this was too brute forced(?) and wondered if there was a more intuitive way of doing something like this.

Comment: Maybe except for simplifying to `var mArray = [correct_answer].concat(incorrect_answers);` (or `[correct_answer, ...incorrect_answers]` in modern JS), that's about what you should do.

Comment: I would do like `incorrect_answers.concat(correct_answer).shuffle()`

Comment: Doesn't this belong on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?